# Url Action not working properly on .Net 6 (not generating link)

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, email, backend

So i'm trying to authenticate my email in .Net 6 core application but without front end (without cshtml), only by sending email,clicking the link and changing the EmailConfirmed box on the user from false to true.
However i have some problem with generating link form Url.Action which i use to send email with the link

```
            var confirmationLink = Request.Scheme + "://" + Request.Host + Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Register",new { code = code,userId = userToAdd.Id });
            Console.WriteLine(confirmationLink);
```

When i do this i get this output

[image]

and nothing else.

This is my ConfirmEmail action which the email should redirect to but when i do this i get 404 and no action from this controller is triggered.

```
       [HttpPost]
        [Route("ConfirmEmail/{token}/{userId}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> EmailAuthentication([FromRoute]string token, [FromRoute]string userId) {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
            Console.WriteLine(user.Email);
            Console.WriteLine(user.UserName);
            Console.WriteLine(token);
            Console.WriteLine(user.EmailConfirmationToken);
            Console.WriteLine(token == user.EmailConfirmationToken);
            if(user == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            if (token == user.EmailConfirmationToken)
            {
                user.EmailConfirmed = true;
                return Ok();
            }
            return BadRequest();
        }
```

And this is the email sender:

```
    public async Task SendEmailAsync(string toEmail, string subject, string message)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Options.SendGridKey))
        {
            throw new Exception("Null SendGridKey");
        }
        await Execute(Options.SendGridKey, subject, message, toEmail);
    }

    public async Task Execute(string apiKey, string subject, string message, string toEmail)
    {
        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
        var emailPass = _config["emailPassword"];
        var msg = new SendGridMessage()
        {
            From = new EmailAddress("employmentlyy@gmail.com", "wlqegxqlkepwrguh"),
            Subject = subject,
            PlainTextContent = message,
            HtmlContent = message
        };
        msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(toEmail));

        // Disable click tracking.
        // See https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/Settings/tracking.html
        msg.SetClickTracking(false, false);
        var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
        _logger.LogInformation(response.IsSuccessStatusCode
                               ? $"Email to {toEmail} queued successfully!"
                               : $"Failure Email to {toEmail}");
    }
}
```

Comment: When you click a hyperlink, it does a GET request. Not POST. Your action method is marked to only take POST requests.

Comment: Looks like the route is expecting `token` and the url helper is providing `code`.

Comment: @mason ok, but why my url.action does not return anything?